# What causes the "Argument expression expected" error in this Angular 13 app?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular13

I am working on an e-commerce app who's front-end is made in Angular 13.

The below code is intended to *sum the prices* of the items in the cart:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: '.app-top-cart',
  templateUrl: './top-cart.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./top-cart.component.css']
})
export class TopCartComponent implements OnInit {
  cartItems: any = [
    {
      id: 1,
      title: "iPhone 9",
      description: "An apple mobile which is nothing like apple",
      price: 549,
      discountPercentage: 12.96,
      rating: 4.69,
      stock: 94,
      brand: "Apple",
      category: "smartphones",
      thumbnail: "https://dummyjson.com/image/i/products/1/thumbnail.jpg",
      images: [
        "https://dummyjson.com/image/i/products/1/1.jpg",
        "https://dummyjson.com/image/i/products/1/2.jpg",
      ]
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      title: "iPhone X",
      description: "SIM-Free, Model A19211 6.5-inch Super Retina HD display with OLED technology A12 Bionic chip with ...",
      price: 899,
      discountPercentage: 17.94,
      rating: 4.44,
      stock: 34,
      brand: "Apple",
      category: "smartphones",
      thumbnail: "https://dummyjson.com/image/i/products/2/thumbnail.jpg",
      images: [
        "https://dummyjson.com/image/i/products/2/1.jpg",
        "https://dummyjson.com/image/i/products/2/2.jpg",
      ]
    }
  ];

  constructor() { }

  totalPrice: number = 0;

  doTotalPrice(){
    let total = 0,
    this.cartItems.forEach((item: { price: number, quantity: number; }) => {
      total += item.price * item.quantity
    }),
    this.totalPrice = total,
 }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.doTotalPrice();
  }

}
```

#### The problem

The code above does not compile. It gives the error `Argument expression expected` on line 54, where the `doTotalPrice` method closes.

##### Where is my mistake?

Comment: You don't close forEach correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
doTotalPrice(){
    let total = 0,
    this.cartItems.forEach((item: { price: number, quantity: number; }) => {
      total += item.price * item.quantity
    },
    this.totalPrice = total,
 }
```

You do not close your function and you use commas instead of semicolons.

```js
doTotalPrice(){
    let total = 0,
    this.cartItems.forEach((item: { price: number, quantity: number; }) => {
      total += item.price * item.quantity
    });
    this.totalPrice = total;
 }
```

Bonus, cleaner code :

```js
this.totalPrice = this.cartItems.reduce(
  (p, { price, quantity }) => p + price * quantity, 
  0
);
```

Comment: Oh, silly me. That is right.

Comment: Added an edit just for your curiosity

Comment: It does cimile now, but `console.log(this.totalPrice)` returns `NaN`.

Comment: @RazvanZamfir not enough context to help you, but it probably means that one of your items is missing either the `price` or the `quantity`

Comment: Actually, as can be seen in the question, none of the objects has a `quantity ` property, but if I add a default value, I get a compilation error: ` this.cartItems.forEach((item: { price: number, quantity: number = 1; }) => {`

Comment: Well you're the one that used the `quantity` field ...

Answer (score 0):

you must delete the comma  after the forEach();

```
 yourArray.forEach(element=>{
 //do something 
 });
```